# Protobuf-net Append Object Instances into Stream, Deserialize as List

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I store multiple instances of a class in a List and when I close my program I save the List into a file using Serialize method.

However, the size of the List can be huge so I wonder if there is a method to Serialize and append object instances into a file during runtime and then Deserialize the file as List when needed.

If there is a way, can you please share an example?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: @alexander-petrov 's answer works great, and addresses your question completely. It's good manners and correct to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I solved the problem in a different way but yes it works. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of serializing the entire list, you can add individual instances of the object to the file using the `WriteDelimitedTo` method.

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
```

When adding an element, save it to a file. Note `FileMode.Append`.

```
Person person = ...
persons.Add(person);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("persons.dat", FileMode.Append))
{
    person.WriteDelimitedTo(fileStream);
}
```

Don't forget to delete or truncate the file before saving first item, if necessary.

---

During deserialization, we read objects one by one using the `ParseDelimitedFrom` method and add them to the list manually.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("persons.dat", FileMode.Open))
{
    while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
    {
        var person = Person.Parser.ParseDelimitedFrom(fileStream);
        persons.Add(person);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the list before adding items, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers mates. I used SerializeWithLengthPrefix method to save the object instances into a file with FileMode.Append option. To read back the object instances from the file as a List I've just used the Deserialize method. By doing so, I can append serialized object instances into the file, and now I can deserialize the object instances in the file directly into a List.